# Content that uses Flash begins to play in fast forward after 30 mins (or so)

Tags: 12.04, flash

Example: Youtube videos play in fast forward.
Ubuntu 12.04 (x64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this happen because of problems with Pulseaudio.

Check your log files for more info.

Try  restarting the pulseaudio process or killing it with the

```
killall pulseaudio
```

command.

Pulseaudio will restart itself if killed.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System settings --> Sound --> Choose internal speakers, this will fix the super fast forward problem AND the sound issue...